# Meteor: retrieve value from document in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a Collection named "balance". I want to get the value of one document in the collection. In order to get only the latest element in the collection I use this query:

```
db.balance.find().sort({date: -1}).limit(1);
```

There's a column called 'value' and I want to get that.

`db.balance.find().sort({date: -1}).limit(1).value;` however does not show the data I want. It shows nothing:

[image]

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns a cursor. You'll need to convert it to an array in order to actually extract the value. Try this:

```
db.balance.find().sort({date: -1}).limit(1).toArray()[0].value;
```

This is, of course, much easier inside of meteor (either in code or via `meteor shell`) because you can do:

```
Balance.findOne({}, {sort: {date: -1}}).value;
```

Comment: Thank you! A quick question. If I add that value to another value (for example 1 + 2) instead of getting 3 I get 2. Why is that? Is it because they're strings? How do I convert them to integers?

Comment: It looks like they are strings. You should probably just store them as integers in the first place. If they remain as strings, a simple way to add them is to convert them to `Number` objects first - e.g. `Number(value1) + Number(value2)`.